# I cannot pull out $_SESSION values from a named session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have named a session that I can call by using this

```
PRINT_R($_SESSION['SESSIONNAME']);
```

It returns the following out of the session variable.

```
myclass Object ( [mycolumn] => myvalue64 [mycolumn2] => 47 [mycolumn3] => 19   )
```

However when I try to `echo` `mycolumn` like this. It doesn't display the value.

```
echo $_SESSION['myclass']['mycolumn'];
```

I'm on `php 5.3.3` if it helps.

Thanks

Comment: The key `'SESSIONNAME'`  is an object of class `myclass`, not an array, so `$_SESSION['SESSIONNAME']->mycolumn`

Comment: Thanks I tried  $_SESSION['SESSIONNAME']->mycolumn and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
echo $_SESSION->mycolumn
```

or in your case

```
 echo $_SESSION['SESSIONNAME']->mycolumn
```